# Codeigniter: How can I use codeigniter's default view system along with smarty templates

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I don't want to remove smarty templates from controllers. In some actions of controllers, I want to use default view system of codeigniter, while on other actions, I want to keep SMARTY templates as display medium. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been developing a CI Smarty library for Codeigniter. It lets you use default Codeigniter views and lets you render Smarty templates using the Codeigniter template parser as I am extending it.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty

As it stands, it works really well. If you have any problems, log an issue on Github and I'll fix it usually within 24 hours. Other solutions are mostly outdated, my library lets you use new Smarty 3 features like template inheritance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the CodeIgniter Wiki - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Smarty/

And a thread in the official forum:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/60050/

Comment: Repox. I'm not too sure how great that library is you provided a link to. It was created in 2007, and since then Codeigniter 2.0 has been released which slightly changes things compared to the version in use in 2007.

Comment: Well, likewise I'm not sure why anyone wants to use Smarty - but this could perhaps help him create his own implementation instead, to work in CI 2.0.